# unable to convert complex sql query into codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have sql query like this basically i got it from a sql expert :

```
SELECT 
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.project_id, t.project_id) AS project_id,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.project_name, t.project_name) AS project_name,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.parent_id, t.parent_id) AS parent_id,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.recycle_bin, t.recycle_bin) AS recycle_bin,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.creater_id, t.creater_id) AS creater_id
FROM projectdetails AS pd1
JOIN(
  SELECT * FROM projectdetails AS pd
  WHERE pd.parent_id > 0 
    AND pd.recycle_bin > 1
) AS t ON t.parent_id = pd1.project_id
GROUP BY project_id;
```

**what will be the equivalent codeigniter sql query?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using active record you can do so

```
$this->db
     ->select('*')
     ->from('projectdetails pd')
     ->where('pd.parent_id > 0  AND pd.recycle_bin > 1',null,FALSE);   
$joinquery = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select(); 

$query=$this->db
      ->select(' if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.project_id, t.project_id) AS project_id,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.project_name, t.project_name) AS project_name,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.parent_id, t.parent_id) AS parent_id,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.recycle_bin, t.recycle_bin) AS recycle_bin,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.creater_id, t.creater_id) AS creater_id' ,FALSE)
     ->from('projectdetails  pd1')
     ->join('($joinquery)  t','t.parent_id = pd1.project_id')
     ->group_by('project_id')
     ->having('creater_id= 7923')
     ->get();
```

Or simply use `query()` function

```
$query =$this->db->query('your full query');
```

**Edit from comments**

```
$this->db->query('SELECT 
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.project_id, t.project_id) AS project_id,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.project_name, t.project_name) AS project_name,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.parent_id, t.parent_id) AS parent_id,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.recycle_bin, t.recycle_bin) AS recycle_bin,
  if(pd1.recycle_bin >1, pd1.creater_id, t.creater_id) AS creater_id
FROM projectdetails AS pd1
JOIN(
  SELECT * FROM projectdetails AS pd
  WHERE pd.parent_id > 0 
    AND pd.recycle_bin > 1
) AS t ON t.parent_id = pd1.project_id
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING creater_id= 7923
');
```

Comment: @user2173803 see my updated answer,for checing column no this is not possible by using * you have to hard code if checks for columns

Comment: remove semicolon after having() function